# Regex: I would like to use Regular Expression to manipulate/change a specific phrase.

Tags: java, android, regex

I have the following String/text:

> It was very hot today, even by local standards, and the only other
>   fossils we found in the quarry during the rest of our searching were
>   small, unidentifiable fragments of bone. The plan for tomorrow is to
>   do more prospecting for fossils in a couple of other quarries in the
>   area.

I need have to follow these rules:

- all words greater than 2 characters should be truncated after the second character and suffixed with the string "-xx"; for example the english word "the" becomes "th-xx"
- capitalization must be maintained
- punctuation must be maintained, unless it appears in a part of the word to be truncated

I would like to use some sort of regular expression to scan through the text and change it according to the rules described above. This is on Android/Java, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The last condition seems pointless: you don't have any punctuation that's part of a word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
String repl = input.replaceAll("\\b([a-zA-Z]{2})[a-zA-Z]+\\b", "$1-xx");
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aV2fB8/1)

Comment: this example works perfectly, also the link provided "RegEx Demo" is very useful to try out other examples, great insight.